# Joining multiple tables for a single report in Django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

From the example dataset below, how would I query, either through django.db or through the database API to get the request result?

I want to query the data set to get all items new than a specified date in A, but I only want the name and color from B and the taste from C.

```
class A(models.Model):
    export_date = models.DateField()

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    color = models.CharField()
    weight = models.CharField()
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

class C(models.Model):
    taste = models.CharField()
    smell = models.CharField()
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

EDIT:
I can do

```
as = A.objects.all().filter(export_date__gte=date)
b = B.objects.all().filter(a=as)
c = B.objects.all().filter(c=as)
```

but then I'm still stuck with two separate query sets that I have to figure out how to manually join.

Comment: This could help. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I can generate a query from class A and then filter class B with this query. I'm still stuck with trying to filter class C the same when and then manually combining the data.

Comment: If you will combine the data manually I think there's not problem. You could do something like `a_list = A.objects.filter(export_date=whateverdate)` and then get from `B` and `C`: b_data = `B.objects.filter(a__in=a_list).values('name', 'color')` and `c_data = C.objects.filter(a__in=a_list).values('taste')`. Then you could combine `b_data` with `c_data` maybe using `A` object as key. Make me know if help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

### myapp/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    export_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "date: {0}".format(self.export_date)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "name: {0}, color: {1}, weight: {2}".format(self.name,
                                                           self.color,
                                                           self.weight)

class C(models.Model):
    taste = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    smell = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "taste: {0}, smell: {1}".format(self.taste, self.smell)
```

### myapp/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import *

admin.site.register(A)
admin.site.register(B)
admin.site.register(C)
```

### myapp/tests.py

```
from myapp.models import A, B, C

A.objects.values('b__color', 'c__taste', 'c__smell')\
         .order_by('id') \
         .distinct()
```

### data

A:

```
- date: 2015-06-10
- date: 2015-06-09
```

B:

```
- (A: 2015-06-09) name: name 2, color: white, weight: 10 kg
- (A: 2015-06-09) name: name 1, color: black, weight: 1 kg
```

C:

```
- (A: 2015-06-09) taste: vanilla, smell: peppermint
- (A: 2015-06-09) taste: pizza, smell: coffee
```

### query output

```
[
    {'b__color': u'black', 'c__taste': u'pizza', 'c__smell': u'coffee'}, 
    {'b__color': u'black', 'c__taste': u'vanilla', 'c__smell': u'peppermint'}, 
    {'b__color': u'white', 'c__taste': u'pizza', 'c__smell': u'coffee'}, 
    {'b__color': u'white', 'c__taste': u'vanilla', 'c__smell': u'peppermint'}, 
    {'b__color': None, 'c__taste': None, 'c__smell': None}
]
```

Comment: The tests.py file, in particular, was the helpful piece. Knowing now that I can string values from other tables into the filter I was generating is a huge help!

Answer (score 2):

```
class A(models.Model):
    export_date = models.DateField()

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    color = models.CharField()
    weight = models.CharField()
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='bs')

class C(models.Model):
    taste = models.CharField()
    smell = models.CharField()
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='cs')

as_result = A.objects.filter(export_date__gte=date)

for a in as_result:
    for b in a.bs:
        print b.name
        print b.color
    for c in a.cs:
        print c.taste
```

If you don't have more than one B and C for each A, consider using [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) relationships.